# How to add additional info on java constraints

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator

With java validation constraints, i.e.

```
@NotNull, @Size, etc
```

You can add a message field that your api can return to the client. Is there anyway to add additional fields such as a custom code?

The problem I have is that every possible error needs it's own message and code return to the client. (By code I mean a custom one in the response body, not a http status code).

I.e.

```
{
  message: foo can not be null,
  code: 10001
}
```

The only thing I can think of is to use custom validator classes on every single field which would be quite a lot of work, or have a giant if/else block that sets the code based on the message.

Can anyone think of a nicer solution?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: How about formatting your message as "10001|foo can not be null", and then split any message you get and parse the code from the first part and the message from the second part?

Comment: That's the solution I'm currently going with. It's still not very nice. Another problem is that my error messages are in a ValidationMessages.properties file and injected as message="{Missing.foo}". To include the code in the message, the codes will also have to be in the ValidationMessages.properties file as well. Again, it's not a very nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `payload()` parameter defined by all constraint types.

You'd have to declare a class type for each one of your error codes:

```
public interface Error_01 {}
```

And then:

```
public class SomeValidatedClass {
    @NotNull(payload=Error_01.class)
    private String someField;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like that might be a nicer solution.